# How to paginate with string provided in JSON result?

Tags: json, rss, feedly

I am using Feedly API to access feeds from a particular rss feed. Take a look at this link (1). As you see, it only returns newest 20 items but I think it provides sort of a link to paginate to the next result. There is 'continuation' key provided in the result but it is a string and not a link.

How can I use that to fetch the next result? Is this even possible?

[JSON response from the server](https://cloud.feedly.com/v3/streams/contents?streamId=feed%2Fhttp%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.engadget.com%2Fweblogsinc%2Fengadget)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://developer.feedly.com/v3/streams/

You can pass the continuation key to get the next batch of results.

For example: https://cloud.feedly.com/v3/streams/contents?streamId=feed/http://feeds.engadget.com/weblogsinc/engadget?continuation=14de41de03e:f7bda:87649ed8